# What blender is required to create an emulsion?

Tags: equipment, emulsion

Let's consider for specificity an emulsion prepared with the use of a protein possessing emulsifying properties as an emulsifying agent. Domestically most commonly prepared protein-based emulsion is mayonnaise.

Recently [Cook's Illustrated](https://www.cooksillustrated.com/articles/382-testing-immersion-blenders) has complicated matters by reporting that at least one of the blenders they tested using a tachometer has the blade rotating at a speed, which does not correspond to the specified by the manufacturer. It looks like these findings were not replicated by other teams. Defects are not uncommon in production of household appliances, but if it is not a problem to measure temperature within an electric oven using a thermometer, measuring speed of rotation is not as easy since a tachometer also has to be tested for accuracy of performance. Yet the speed of rotation is a critical determinant of emulsification efficiency. What also is of interest is that manufacturers like KitchenAid (probably the second most highly rated brand after Vitamix) do not specify the speed of rotation of their blenders’ blade, so a blender suitable as an emulsification device can be five times less expensive than renowned for high speed alternatives if it meets minimum speed and power requirements.

So I would like to know whether anyone here has experience of using different blenders for emulsification and does not mind to share it with others.

Comment: It's possible to create an emulsion like mayonnaise using a hand whisk, so I doubt you're going to find a particularly satisfying answer if you are expecting a certain minimum velocity or specific type of blender.

Comment: From what I can read from the link, they all work equally good in all their tests; pick one within your budget

Comment: The body of this question and the headline don't quite line up. The answer to the heading question is "no" (as @dbmag9 mentions), but the body of the main question seems to assume "yes" and dives into a different direction around blender speed & selecting a blender.

Comment: @AMtwo But my point was also that, since you can make an emulsion using a hand whisk, blender speed and type are not going to be that critical.

Answer (score 4):

An emulsion, like mayonnaise, can be made with a fork, a hand whisk, an electric whisk, a stick blender, or a traditional blender with a jar. I've made mayo, at some point or another, with just about all of these.  For home use, the hand whisk is often the most convenient if you are handy with the technique.  However, I find a stick blender to be the best option, for speed and easy cleanup.  One caveat is that the container you are making the mayo in should be just slightly larger than the blade end of the stick blender.  For me, a cocktail shaker is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming for best results you might be interested in having a look on devices that are sold as Turbo-Mixers or Homogenizers. They are similar to usual immersion blenders but equipped with a special head to create higher shearing power and used where regularly large quantities of emulsions are prepared like in ice cream making. The downside is the price tag of this tool, starting at around 250 $ for a home sized model.